# ActiveRecord query to sum nested object values and compare against the parent model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model named `Appointment` which has a `has_many :invoices` association with `Invoice`.

`Appointment` also has a `grand_total` bigdecimal field, while `Invoice` has an `amount` bigdecimal field.

I'd like to create a query saying `select all Appointments whose invoices' amounts sum is greater or equal to 50% of grand_total`.

Actually I select all Appointments, loop them and perform that check as follows

```
@selected_appointments = []
Appointments.all.each do |appointment|
  invoices_sum = BigDecimal.new(0)

  appointment.invoices.each do |invoice|
    invoices_sum += invoice.amount
  end

  if invoices_sum >= (appointment.grant_total/2)
    @selected_appointments.push(appointment)
  end
end
```

But this doesn't really seem to be to be a good option since it's really slow.

Can you give me some help?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you:

```
Appointment.select("appointments.*, sum(invoice.amount) invoices_total")
           .joins(:invoices)
           .group(:appointment_id)
           .having('invoices_total >= (appointment.grant_total/2)')
```